# Promote Library Column Data To Infopath Form

Tags: infopath

I have a document library on SharePoint 2013 with an Infopath 2010 form as a template. Currently when the form gets submitted a workflow runs on the library to get authorisation details from another list and updates columns in the library with the info, it also creates a unique ID for the document.

Currently my infopath form seems to be able to read this info from the document library and I can't seem to find out how. It looks like it is using property promotion but from the library to the form but when I add additional columns I created it doesn't seem to be able to read these. Any ideas how the form is doing this and how can I get my additional columns into the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that when using form options to promote properties from infopath there wasn't an option to allow data to be editable. I used the publishing wizard and the option was available.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you would not add fields to the SharePoint library and then try to get them into the Infopath form. This is the wrong way around. Instead, you'd first create fields in the InfoPath form field structure, then promote these fields to SharePoint columns.

The fields that have been promoted to SharePoint columns can, of course, be populated with a workflow.

Comment: Thanks for your input but none of the fields that I have promoted from infopath are available to update via my workflow. They are read only in the document library also, but the fields that are currently working as I indicated are editable in my document library and updatable via workflows. I'm using nintex workflow 2013 also.

Comment: Figured out that when using form options to promote properties from infopath there wasn't an option to allow data to be editable. I used the publishing wizard and the option was available.